# accessing a nested array to populate tableview in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, decodable

here is my model class I can access the TotalMeetings and FriendsDetail but unable to access MeetingsDetail

```
struct TotalMeetings: Decodable {
var status: Int
var message: String
var friends: [FriendDetail]?
}
struct FriendDetail: Decodable {
var id: Int
var meetings: [MeetingsDetail]
}
struct MeetingsDetail: Decodable {
var meeting_id: Int
var meeting_with: String
}
```

This is how am parsing my response and can get successfully the value of **FriendDetail** but how do I get the values e.g. meeting_id from the **MeetingsDetail**

```
var friendsArr = [FriendDetail]()
meetingsData = try decoder.decode(TotalMeetings.self, from: response.data!)
friendsArr = meetingsData.friends
```

This is how im populating the tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friendsArr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FriendsMeetingTVC

    cell.emailLbl.text = friendsArr[indexPath.row].email //successful
   // let meetingId = friendsArr[indexPath.row].meetings[indexPath.row].id // im trying this way but it show an error stating index out of range
  //  cell.userIdLbl.text = String(meetingId) 

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the table view, e.g. how do you calculate numberOfRows and numberOfSections?

Comment: Hey @AndreasOetjen please check again

Comment: So there is only one section? How will you handle multiple meetings then?

Comment: one user can have only one meeting at a time I dont know why would they make it an array for a user

Comment: @MuhammadBilal you need to override `numberOfSection` method of `UITableView` and return `meetingsData.count` and later in `cellForRow` method check `indexPath.section` for meetings and `indexPath.row` for friends.

Comment: If there is only one meeting, you can use this: `meetingId = friendsArr[indexPath.row].meetings[0].id` -- but this only works if there always is a meeting; otherwise you'll have to check it before